# How to separate a CSV file when there are "" lines?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

When I am reading in a CSV file that looks like this:

```
To, ,New York ,Norfolk ,Charleston ,Savannah 

Le Havre (Fri), ,15 ,18 ,22 ,24 

Rotterdam (Sun) ,"",13 ,16 ,20 ,22 

Hamburg (Thu) ,"",11 ,14 ,18 ,20 

Southampton (Fri) , "" ,8 ,11 ,15 ,17
```

using pandas, as follows:

```
duration_route1 =  pd.read_csv(file_name, sep = ',')
```

I get the following result (I use Sublime Text to run my Python code):

[image]

You see that when there is a `""`, it doesn't separate the string. Why does it not do this?

Comment: Could you show what the CSV *actually* looks like, in text form rather than Excel? Have you tried explicitly setting a quote char?

Comment: For me it works very nice.

Comment: Can you upload your sample file to dropbox or gdocs for test?

Comment: @jezrael please don't encourage people to upload files elsewhere, they should put a [mcve] **in the question** to avoid link rot.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - hmmm, you are right, but it seems file is broken or some weird thing. How is other way for test it as uploat problematic file? I have no idea.

Comment: I add the file (in text form) in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` because there are `quoting` in `file`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('TAT_AX1_westbound_style3.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
print (df)
                    To          New York   Norfolk   Charleston  Savannah 
0       Le Havre (Fri)                 15        18           22       24 
1    "Rotterdam (Sun)     """"         13        16           20      22 "
2      "Hamburg (Thu)     """"         11        14           18      20 "
3  "Southampton (Fri)    """"           8        11           15      17 "
```

```
#remove first column 
df = df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1)
#remove all " values to empty string, convert to int
df = df.replace({'"':''}, regex=True).astype(int)
print (df)
                     New York   Norfolk   Charleston   Savannah 
To                                                              
Le Havre (Fri)              15        18           22         24
"Rotterdam (Sun)            13        16           20         22
"Hamburg (Thu)              11        14           18         20
"Southampton (Fri)           8        11           15         17     15       17
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use csv library in python, 
import it and use .

```
import csv

file_obj = #your_file_object_read_mode
rows = file_obj.readlines()

for raw in csv.DictReader(rows, delimiter=","):
    print(raw) # the raw will be a dictionary and you can use it well for any need.
```

each raw will look like ie,

```
{'number3': '88', 'number2': '22', 'name': 'vipul', 'number1': '23'}
```

This solves your problem I think, Just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

From your sample you have provided, it is clear that the problem is with the data set and pandas is working correctly.

Only the first row is separated correctly, the second row is all in one column; as a single string (pay attention to the `"`). If I replace the `,` with `|`, your problem becomes a bit clearer:

```
To                                        | |New York |Norfolk |Charleston |Savannah 
Le Havre (Fri)                            | |15       |18      |22         |24 
"Rotterdam (Sun) ,"""",13 ,16 ,20 ,22 "   | 
"Hamburg (Thu) ,"""",11 ,14 ,18 ,20 "     |
"Southampton (Fri) , """" ,8 ,11 ,15 ,17 "|
```

Now you have to manually split the second row in order to create the correct data set.

```
>>> with open('sample2.txt') as f:
...    headers = next(f).split(',')
...    rows = [i.split(',') for i in f]
...
>>> rows = [list(map(str.strip, list(map(lambda x: x.replace('"', ''), i)))) for i in rows]
>>> pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)
                  To   New York Norfolk Charleston Savannah
0     Le Havre (Fri)         15      18         22       24
1    Rotterdam (Sun)         13      16         20       22
2      Hamburg (Thu)         11      14         18       20
3  Southampton (Fri)          8      11         15       17
```